# Why does value of local variable change at every execution using OpenMP?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, race-condition

This is a program which I had had some other issues with before regarding optimization, but now I am stuck with a problem with data-race in it.

So I have a function that will scan a text (`lines`) for certain words (`words`). I parallelized the outer for loop using `#pragma omp parallel for`. The loop scans the text for one word in each iteration and counts its occurrences, and for this I set `total_word_count` to `0` at the start of every iteration.

The inner for loop then loops through the lines of the text and checks if the current line contains the given word. It counts both the word's occurrence by line and the total number of occurrence of the word in the whole text.

```c
double analyze_text(char **lines, char *words[], size_t nr_lines, int nr_words, int k) {
        start();

#       pragma omp parallel for num_threads(k) \
        default(none)  shared(lines, nr_words, nr_lines, words)
//scans the text nr_words times, once for each word
        for (int i=0; i<nr_words; i++) {
//this will count the occurrence of the word in the whole text
                int total_word_count = 0;
                printf("The word is: %s.\nSEARCHING...\n", words[i]);
//loops through the lines
                for (size_t j=0; j<nr_lines; j++) {
//this will count the occurence of the word in the current line
                        int word_occurence = 0;
//let's check whether the line contains the word
                        if (strstr(lines[j], words[i]) != NULL) {
                                printf("Word found at line %ld, position(s): ", j);
                                char line[MAX_L_LENGTH];
                                strcpy(line, lines[j]);
                                char delim[] = " -";
                                char *ptr = strtok(line, delim);
                                int counter =  0;
//let's find every occurence of the word in the current line
                                while (ptr != NULL) {
                                        counter++;
                                        char found_word[strlen(words[i])+1];
                                        strncpy(found_word, ptr, strlen(words[i]));
                                        found_word[strlen(found_word)] = '\0';
                                        if (strcmp(words[i], found_word) == 0) {
                                                word_occurence++;
                                                printf("%d ", counter);
                                        }
                                        ptr =  strtok(NULL, delim);
                                }
                                printf("\nline[%3zu]: %s\n", j, lines[j]);
                        }
                        total_word_count += word_occurence;
                }
                printf("The word appears %d times in the text in total.\n\n", total_word_count);
        }
        stop();
        return ClockCounter;
}
```

The problem is that I get different results for `total_word_count` for each word at every execution. When I run the sequential version of this same program I get the correct results for a certain array of words, but with the parallelized version the results will either slightly alter (differ with +-2-3) or apparently accumulate (differ with ~ +200-300). I tried declaring `total_word_count` outside the for loop and make a reduction, and reset it to 0 at the beginning of every iteration, but that doesn't work either. I think there must be some data race with both variable `word_occurence` and variable `total_word_count`. There is a third variable I use, `counter`, this is to count the position of a certain word in a line and print it at every occurrence in case the word is present multiple times in a line.

I don't know what scope to set these variables to since I expect them to be private if they are declared *inside* the `for` loop, meaning that the threads shouldn't change each other's variables. Yet I get different results at every execution, sometimes apparently just a bit lower the accurate result, but sometimes very large counts.

What is the issue with my code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I tried declaring total_word_count outside the for loop and make a reduction" That is the correct solution. "and reset it to 0 at the beginning of every iteration". That's obviously wrong. Zero it before the whole parallel region.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you, but that would mean that `total_word_count` is not reset to 0 after finishing with one word. I need to count the occurrence for every word separately and this is why I need the variable reset inside the parallel region, for every iteration. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: This question was answered by JeromeRichard's comment in your previous question. `strtok` is not threadsafe. Use `strtok_r` and also consider his other comments. (`man strtok` says "* The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe. Use strtok_r() if this matters to you." )

Comment: @Laci thank you, I think the method change solved the problem. I didn't know `strtok` was not thread-safe. Also, what I thought was an accumulation of counts is actually just a different count being logged in a random order by one of the threads compared to the last logged count result of the sequential program (so the values are not logged in the same order in the two versions and this led me to think that the last result was the sum of the others). I think it works now as expected. Could you please phrase this into an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Well, you should thank Jerome,too. Note also that your current code finds sub-strings as well. E.g. if you search for "tall" but your text contains "taller" it is a hit. Is this your intention?

Comment: @Laci I did, thanks for the reminder. And yes, I intend to find whole words (e.g. _thought_, that's why the space delimiter), partial words (e.g. _thoughtful_, the word is part of a compound word), and words that have the word as a prefix (e.g. _thought-provoking_).

Comment: My suggestion is that you should try to fix your code and if you are successful answer your own question, if not, please update your question and tell us where you stuck with it.